# react js firebase firestore- how to update document in sub collection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i want to update my sub collection document the parent collection is "Exams"

[image: this is the screenshot of my firestore database]

this is what the examtable.jsx look like, this is where the questions are displayed

```js
import "./questiontable.css"
import { DataGrid} from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"
import { getDocs, collection , onSnapshot,  deleteDoc,  doc , updateDoc } from '@firebase/firestore'
import { db } from '../../firebase'
import React, { useEffect, useState,useRef } from 'react'
import { useParams , useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import Table from '@mui/material/Table';
import TableBody from '@mui/material/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@mui/material/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@mui/material/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@mui/material/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@mui/material/TableRow';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';



 export const Questiontable = () => {

    const [getDocs,setgetDocs] = useState([])
    const {id}=useParams()
    const isMounted = useRef()
    const collectionRef = collection(db, "Exams",id,"qna")
    let navigate = useNavigate();

    const getData = () => {
        onSnapshot(collectionRef, (data) => {
          setgetDocs(data.docs.map((doc) => {
                return {...doc.data(), id: doc.id}
            }))
            
        })
          }
    
        useEffect(() => {
          if(isMounted.current){
              return 
          }
    
          isMounted.current = true;
          getData()
        }, []);

        const getID = (id) => {
          navigate(`update_question/${id}`)
      }

    return (
      
        <TableContainer component={Paper} className="table">
          <div className="examtableTitle">
                 Questions
                
                 <Link to={`add_question/${id}`} style={{textDecoration:"none", float:"right",  border: "1px solid green", padding:"9px",
                          borderRadius: "5px", cursor: "pointer", marginRight:"10px"}}  className="link">
                     Add new
                 </Link>
             </div>
          <Table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell className="tableCell">Question</TableCell>
                <TableCell className="tableCell">Choices</TableCell>
                <TableCell className="tableCell">Action</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
            {getDocs.map((doc) => {
              return(
                <TableRow key={doc.id} >
                  <TableCell className="tableCell" > {doc.question}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell className="tableCell">{doc.correctanswer} [{doc.incorrectanswer}]</TableCell>
                  <TableCell className="tableCell">
                  <div className="cellAction">
                    <div className="manageButton" onClick={() => getID(doc.id)}>Manage</div>
                    <div className="deleteButton" >Delete</div>
                  </div>
                  </TableCell>
                  
                </TableRow>
              )
              })}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      );
}

export default Questiontable
```

now this is the updatequestion.jsx where all the updates will happen

```js
import "./newQuestion.scss"
import Sidebar from '../../components/sidebar/Sidebar'
import Navbar from '../../components/navbar/Navbar'
import { useEffect, useState , useRef } from 'react'
import { db } from '../../firebase'
import { getDoc , onSnapshot,updateDoc,  doc, collection} from '@firebase/firestore'
import { useParams , useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';


const UpdateQuestion = (id) => {
  
  let params = useParams();
  
  const [question, setQuestion] = useState('');
  const [correctanswer, setCorrectAnswer]=useState("");
  const [optionone,setOptionOne]=useState("")
  const [optiontwo,setOptionTwo]=useState("");
  const [optionthree,setOptionThree]=useState("");
  // const collectionRef = collection(db, 'Exams')

  function handleUpdate(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const examcollref = doc(db,"Exams",params.id,"qna",params.id)
    updateDoc(examcollref,{
      question:question,
      correctanswer:correctanswer,
      optionone:optionone,
      optiontwo:optiontwo,
      optionthree:optionthree
    } ).then(response => {
      alert("updated")
      console.log(getDoc(params.id))
    }).catch(error =>{
      console.log(error.message)
    })
   
  } 
 
  return (

    <div className="newQuestion">
    <Sidebar/>
    <div className="newQuestionContainer">
        <Navbar/>
        <div className="leftContainer">
        <div className="leftTitle">
         Add Question
        </div>
        <br />
          <form onSubmit={handleUpdate}>
             <label htmlFor="">Questions</label>
             <input type="text" 
              placeholder="question"
              onChange={e =>setQuestion(e.target.value)}
              value={question} />
             <h6>Input words for choices</h6>

          <label htmlFor="">Choice A</label>
          <input type="text" 
          placeholder='Input Choice A'
          onChange={e => setOptionOne(e.target.value)}
          value={optionone}/>
          <label htmlFor="">Choice B</label>
          <input type="text" 
          placeholder='Input Choice B'
          onChange={e => setOptionTwo(e.target.value)}
          value={optiontwo}/>
          <label htmlFor="">Choice C</label>
          <input type="text" 
          placeholder='Input Choice C'
          onChange={e => setOptionThree(e.target.value)}
          value={optionthree}/>
          
          <label htmlFor="">Correct Answer</label>
          <input type="text" 
          placeholder='Correct Answer'
          onChange={e => setCorrectAnswer(e.target.value)}
          value={correctanswer}/>

          <button button="submit">Add</button>
          </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  )
}

export default UpdateQuestion
```

maybe my problem here is this line?

```js
 const examcollref = doc(db,"Exams",params.id,"qna",params.id)
```

because ive got an error message

```
No document to update: projects/oems-development/databases/(default)/documents/Exams/TUsw0lJDmq3GSrH6a8MN/qna/TUsw0lJDmq3GSrH6a8MN
```

here is the error that i recieved on console

Comment: If you want to update all fields then you must pass them in updateDoc(). Currently you are just passing question in the function.

Comment: i did that just to check if its working, i also added all the fields yesterday but nothing updating

Comment: maybe the problem here is the calling the document id of sub collection, do you have idea about that?

Answer (score 0):

I can point to two methods that you can use to update sub-collection in Firestore:

**Method 1:**

You can try something like below using set() method.

```
const examcollref = firebase.firestore().collection(“exams”).doc(params.id).collection("qna");

await examcollref.doc(params.id)
.set({ question:question, correctanswer:correctanswer, optionone:optionone, optiontwo:optiontwo, optionthree:optionthree, updatedAt: date, }) .catch((err) => { console.log(err) }) }
```

You can look into this [stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63862883/15774177) for more information.

**Method 2:**

You can try using a collection group if you have the same collection inside each document of the main collection. This makes it easier for you to write the code without much confusion. You can read more about the collection group [here](https://firebase.blog/posts/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries).

To use the collection group to update the fields you have to first store the snapshot of the collection and then update it, as shown below:

```
const querySnapshot = await db .collectionGroup(“qna”).get(); 
querySnapshot.docs.forEach(snapshot => { snapshot.ref.update(...) })
```

You can look into this [stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59043238/15774177) for more information.

Comment: thank you i will let you know if it worked :)